# celery worker sub process kill if the request comes again for same

Tags: python, redis, celery, django-celery

is there anyone who can help me out? Like suppose if the same kind of request comes again for same worker so i want to kill all process for same task id to their respective sub process. How Can i achieve this  ? I want to use redis as Cache Server.